# Is there an option in Visual Studio 2022 to keep 'Task Runner Explorer' open continuously during debugging

Tags: visual-studio

When I start debugging in Visual Studio, the Task Runner Explorer disappears.

[image]

Is there a way to keep the Task Runner Explorer open even during debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several iterations, I found the 'Task Runner Explorer' window that works during debugging.

To have the 'Task Runner Explorer' open during debugging, simply select 'View > Other Windows > Task Runner Explorer' while debugging.

It appears that the 'Task Runner Explorer,' which seems to be managed separately from build times, opens.
However, the ongoing tasks continue to be displayed as they were.